# Can't receive JSON string from PHP file in Android

Tags: java, php, android, json, httpurlconnection

below I include some of my code:

Here is my code:

```
int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode==-1) { httpCon.connect(); }

InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream();
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(line);
}
rd.close();

try {

    OutputStream file = openFileOutput("configND", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    DataOutputStream wrf = new DataOutputStream(file);
    wrf.writeBytes(line);
    wrf.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying receive data (JSON string) from PHP file and then create a file with a content but something is wrong. I can't receive a JSON string and the file can not be created.

I use HttpURLconnection and I don't use apache library. I might add that sending JSON is working properly.

Help!

Comment: so you want to ask a server that is running php to send your android some json file right?

Comment: sending data is working. This is OK, but I can't receive a data as JSON string.

Comment: can you log "response.toString()" after your loop?

Comment: also make sure you set permission in the manifest file

Comment: permissions are given.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> With the log I have a problem. I can't read a logs. I'm new in android. This is my first app. I'm using android-studio.

Comment: Edit your question, post the parser, the AndroidManifest.... also, like `arshadkazmi42` answered, if you dont need to do criptic connections, then check Volley, it is significantly better than managing connections, and it covers most if not all Android versions

Answer (score 0):

If you receive nothing from the server, the problem might be simply in your PHP script.

For the Android part of the "problem", if you don't want to use Volley and simply handle this with Android APIs, these two links should make your day :)

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php

Personnally, when I learned Android some years ago, I followed AndroidHive ressources and it works pretty well.

Comment: This is sample of my PHP Code:

`<?php
$data = array("random" => 52847293039);
echo json_encode($data);
?>`

I would like receive variable random in Java. I'll read about Volley library but now I have dead line and my app is almost finished. I would like to leave HttpURLConnection.